# Generate several Object using Scala ForAll

Tags: scala, forall

I have this simple object:

```
class person {

val name:String
val age:Int
}
```

And this is how i am generate several objects:

```
object Generate {

    def person() = for {

        name <- // ...
        age <- // ...

      } yield Person(name, age)
}
```

Usage:

```
    forAll(
      Generate.person(),
      Generate.person(),
      Min(2)) { (person1, person2) =>

      // Here i have this 2 `Person` objects
      }
```

My question:

So in case i want to generate for example 100 `Person` objects, any suggestion how to do that without specify this way ?

```
        forAll(
          Generate.person(),
          Generate.person(),
          Min(100)) { 
(person1, person2, person3, person4, person5 ........, person100) =>
          }
```

Comment: Good luck with that `Tuple100` :D How about generating a `List`?

Comment: sound fine, any example ?

Comment: what about just using `Vector.fill(100){ Generate.person() }` ?

Comment: I am not experienced in scalacheck but I think you might just want to check your property for lists of persons with arbitrary length, not exactly 100. If that is the case I think you could just do `forAll { ps: List[person] => ... }` if you have implicit generator for `person` in scope.

Comment: When you run forall you will get one by one all objects from the generator. I can hardly imagine you need all 100 at the same time (and you can't have tuple of 100)

Comment: @Hüseyin Zengin, in my example i have this person1, person2 that i can reach and check properties etc. how can i get the current Person in your example ?

Comment: @davidhol `val people = Vector.fill(100){ Generate.person() }
val person1 = people(0)`
Vector is just a list